# Yocto post script to move two deployed image files into a folder

Tags: yocto

I'm trying to create a recipe that moves two image archives and places them into a directory inside Yocto's deploy directory `/tmp/deploy/images`. I have already created a new image that simply includes the other two recipes, however I haven't been able to utilize any of the available scripting functions to copy the generated images into a separate folder scheme. I've tried using `do_install_append()` to simply touch a new file, but to no avail and no warnings/errors are shown inside of the terminal during image creation.

Essentially, the workflow would be as follows inside of `my-image.bb`

```
....
require my-1st-image.bb
require my-2nd-image.bb

post_script(){

# rm -rf ${WORKDIR}/images/<machine>/USB 
# mkdir ${WORKDIR}/images/<machine>/USB
# cp <my-1st-image.tar.gz> ${WORKDIR}/images/<machine>/USB
# cp <my-2nd-image.tar.gz> ${WORKDIR}/images/<machine>/USB

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `install`

Try the following

```
post_script() {
    install -d ${WORKDIR}/images/<machine>/USB
    install -m 0755 <my-1st-image.tar.gz>  ${WORKDIR}/images/<machine>/USB
    install -m 755 <my-2nd-image.tar.gz> ${WORKDIR}/images/<machine>/USB
}
```

The first of the 3 install commands above will create a working directory. The other two will copy the files.